# Creating a Standalone Node.js WEBAPP

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Please note that I'm looking to create a webapp, not an executable or native application.

I have created a node.js application using express, react, and webpack. I'd like to be able to package and deploy the website and have it run on other computers (no internet connection) but still in a browser. Just by opening an index.html file in Chrome or something similar without having node installed or running any local servers. Just open the index in Chrome and away it goes. Is this possible? How can I go about doing so?

Comment: Does your app talk to server?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are interesting, but it might be difficult to run node.js if they don't have it installed. Definitely sounds like something you want to package, maybe in a self-containing binary.

Take a look at [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). It powers Atom and supports node.js. Also comes with a bundled Chromium browser.